# Is there a "mysqli_fetch_all" using column (PK) as index in resulting array?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

Currently I have something to the effect:

```
<?php

  // ...More Code

  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM stock_types");
  if(!$result || mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1) die('error');
  $stock_types = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  die(print_r($stock_types,true));

  // More Code...

?>
```

Will output something to the effect:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [type_id] => 1
    [type_name] => In Stock
    [type_visible] => 1
    [type_locked] => 0
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [type_id] => 2
    [type_name] => Out of Stock
    [type_visible] => 1
    [type_locked] => 1
  )
  [2] => Array (
    [type_id] => 3
    [type_name] => Offline
    [type_visible] => 0
    [type_locked] => 1
  )
  [3] => Array (
    [type_id] => 5
    [type_name] => Hidden
    [type_visible] => 0
    [type_locked] => 0
  )
)
```

Is there a mysqli fetch filter (correct term?) that will use the primary key from the result set if one exists as the array index value? In case my question is not clear it would result in something instead to his effect:

```
Array (
  [1] => Array (
    [type_name] => In Stock
    [type_visible] => 1
    [type_locked] => 0
  )
  [2] => Array (
    [type_name] => Out of Stock
    [type_visible] => 1
    [type_locked] => 1
  )
  [3] => Array (
    [type_name] => Offline
    [type_visible] => 0
    [type_locked] => 1
  )
  [5] => Array (
    [type_name] => Hidden
    [type_visible] => 0
    [type_locked] => 0
  )
)
```

It's not essential for the `type_id` values to be removed, but it would be super useful if the Primary Key could be used to index the array. I can do this with a fetch loop but I'm wondering if there is a simpler more elegant way of handling this.

Comment: In case someone is looking for this within wordpress, you can do it with [wpdb::get_results() method](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/), setting the output parameter to `OBJECT_K`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no convenient function for this in ext/mysqli. But you can build the array in the manner you want by fetching the rows one by one and putting them into the right array key:

This example assumes the primary key is the first column:

```
$set = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $set[array_shift($row)] = $row;
}
```

To do it with fetch_all(), you could process the while dataset fetched:

```
$set = array();
$data = $result->fetch_all(); 
while ($row = array_shift($data)) {
    $set[array_shift($row)] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Guess I'll have to stick with the loops then. Thanks for the guidance Bill.

Comment: array_shift works really well, thank you. I wish there was a way to keep the column names in the fetch_all, isntead of having to reference them via key [0], [1], [2], etc.

Answer (score 4):

this is exactly what I am also looking for, here is what simple example with standard php function.This works only if your array is of length 2.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => xxx
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => yyy
        )
)
```

you can make as below format using function: [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
Array
(
    [1] => xxx
    [2] => yyy
)
```

code sample:

```
$result_set = mysqli_fetch_all($restult_set , MYSQLI_ASSOC);
//syntax: array_column(arg, column_key, index_key)
$result_set = array_column($result_set, 'name' , 'id');
```

this works great if you have only array of length of two, saves lot of mysqli call against using it as mysqli_fetch in while loop.Hope this may be usefull.

Comment: +1 Seeing as how the 2nd parameter is that of `mixed`, I'm sure it could be worked to hold an array as well. Good find, I will play around with this and see if I can get it to do what I want.

Comment: **To make this work with more than just two values**, just set the 2nd parameter to `null` and the 3rd parameter to your desired array index value.

Answer (score 0):

It's good thing that you considered some automation. Most PHP users never bother to think of such matters. Let me suggest you [my library](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) which I wrote exclusively to solve this and many other inconveniences of mysqli. Of course it has a ready-made function for the purpose.

Please note the amount of code you need to get your array: its no more than **one line**:

```
$stock_types = $db->getInd('type_id', "SELECT * FROM stock_types");
print_r($stock_types);die;
```

Exactly the same amount of code you will need for almost every other database interaction. Even in case when some variables have to be added into query, which will take raw mysqli huge amount of **constantly repeated** code (you are surely using parameters with mysqli, aren't you?).

For example, here is one of my favorites:

```
$data = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM ?n WHERE id IN (?a) LIMIT ?i",$table,$ids,$limit);
```

It will take you just insane amount of code with raw mysqli, if doing it properly and *safe.* While with properly written abstraction library it's still no more than one line

Comment: Sounds neat! Though I tried going to the github link for your library and it returned a 500 error, so dunno what's up with that. I'll be sure to keep checking back sounds like something I could sink my teeth into for sure!

Comment: sounds strange. it works right now for me. Please keep me in touch. I'll send you a zipped version if it keep with 500